# A question in multivariable calculus related to surjectivity and bijectivity

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

This particular question was asked in a masters exam for which I am studying and I am struglling to do it.

> (a) Show that there exists no bijective map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that f and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable.
>
> (b)Let $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable map such that Df(x) is surjective for all x. Is f surjective?

For (a) , I was unable to argue what result I should use assuming that a map f exists.

(b) I took examples of x, $x^2$ in $\mathbb{R}$ in hope of getting some contradiction but was unable to.

Can you please outline a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a), you can use some linear algebra: Since $f\circ f^{-1}$ and $f^{-1}\circ f$ are the identity on $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^2$, respectively, they are differentiable with full rank differential. In particular, the differential of $f\circ f^{-1}$ has rank $3$. But using the chain rule, the fact that the differential of $f$ has at most rank $2$, and some linear algebra, you can show that the differential of $f\circ f^{-1}$ also has at most rank $2$, a contradiction.

For b), starting with $n=m=1$ was a good idea. Note that in this case, the differential of $f$ being surjective just means that the derivative is not $0$. So you need an example of a function which is differentiable, has nowhere vanishing derivative, and is not surjective. You probably know some of those.

Comment: In (b), I am not able to understand how does derivative being surjective implies that derivative is not 0? Do you meant not identically 0?

Comment: "But using the chain rule, the fact that the differential of f has at most rank 2, and some linear algebra, you can show that the differential of f∘f−1 also has at most rank 2, a contradiction." Can you please  write a complete proof. I am not so good in multivariable calculus.

Comment: The differential is a map. And I'm not talking about the derivative map which maps every point to the differential of $f$ at the point. I'm saying that the differential at a single point is itself a map. A linear one at that. Specifically, if $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, then the differential is a linear map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$. And if $n=m=1$, this makes it just a linear map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. These are all surjective - except the zero map. So for the differential to be surjective, it can't be the zero map.

Comment: To a): $f\circ f^{-1}$ is the identity map on $\mathbb R^3$. The differential of the identity is the identity, which has full rank, so rank 3. But the chain rule says that the differential of $f\circ f^{-1}$ is $\mathrm Df(f^{-1})\circ \mathrm D(f^{-1})$. But both the linear maps in this expression have at most rank 2, because they are maps to or from $\mathbb R^2$, respectively. And composing linear maps of rank at most 2 can only lead to a linear map of at most rank 2. And that's a contradiction, since we had established that it has rank 3.